# Model trained on tf2.3 performs poorly on tf2.6

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've trained a model on tensorflow 2.3 and now am trying inference on tf2.6. The model was originally trained on AWS so the CUDA and CUDNN versions are different, as well as the rest of the environment (python 3.7.11 and 3.8.12, numpy 1.18.5 and numpy 1.19.5).

The model is the exact same, the weights are also the same. However the resulting inference of the same input data results in two different vectors. They are NOT the same, differing substantially.

What is causing this issue and how do I make the results the same?

Comment: Could you share some more details about your model?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but found a workaround. It seems to be keras 2.6.0 being problematic. Downgrading from tf2.6 to tf2.5 makes it fine as the results are the same.